# AsyncHttpClient not working with same data as in HttpClient to log into Salesforce

Tags: android, salesforce, httpclient, asynchttpclient

I'm having trouble trying to find out why I can't get through to Salesforce in my Android Application. The function is as follows:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("grant_type", "password");
    params.put("client_id", API_KEY);
    params.put("client_secret", SECRET_KEY);
    params.put("username", USERNAME);
    params.put("password", String.format("%s%s", PASSWORD, SECURITY_CODE));
    //params.put("username", login);
    //params.put("password", password);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            String accessToken;
            String instanceUrl;
            String tokenType;
            String signature;

            try {
                accessToken = response.getString("access_token");
                instanceUrl = response.getString("instance_url");
                tokenType = response.getString("token_type");
                signature = response.getString("signature");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                callback.onFailure("Error by parsing...");
                return;
            }

            /**
             * After getting the main credential data, we save them in SFSession.
             */
            SFSession.setAccessToken(context, accessToken);
            SFSession.setInstanceUrl(context, instanceUrl);
            SFSession.setTokenType(context, tokenType);
            SFSession.setSignature(context, signature);

            callback.onSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject response) {
            //If the app crashes right here it might just be that you forgot to turn on WiFi.
            callback.onFailure(response.toString());
            Log.e("ERROR", response.toString());
        }
    });
```

I tried building the same logic in a simple Java application that takes the same data, looking like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", API_KEY));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", SECRET_KEY));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", USERNAME));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", String.format("%s%s", PASSWORD, SECURITY_CODE)));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    System.out.println(response.getProtocolVersion());
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        try {
            java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(instream).useDelimiter("\\A");
            System.out.print(s.next());

        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
    }
```

This somehow works. In the Android application I get an error message for not having sent the right username / password, but with the same data in the test application I get my access token back. What could possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between the Java HttpPost and Android AsyncHttpClient Library.

Have you tried adding a Content Type header? Or at least debugging the header?

With OAuth requests I usually use `{ Content-Type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }` and then pass the data inside the POST body.

*Something like this:*

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "grant_type"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "client_id"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "client_secret")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "username"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Comment: I have tried to make this work somehow for a few more hours but just didn't find out how to write something like this - can you please post an example?